# непрерывный мониторинг

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Ниже следует код. Прога открывает окно с кнопками СТАРТ и ФИНИШ. По клику старт начинает стучаться по указанным урлам и проверять их доступность. Если ок, идет дальше. Если сервис не доступен, пишет в окошко. Задача в том, чтобы она бегала по кругу, пока не нажмут кнопку ФИНИШ. Как это сделать?

```
from tkinter import *
import requests


def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text='мониторинг запущен')
    urls = ['https://...', 'https://.....']
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        i = r.status_code
        if i != 200:
            tx.insert(INSERT, "\n\r" + url + " not found")


def click():
    lbl.configure(text='мониторинг остановлен')

def click_sibel():
    lbl.configure(text='Sibel not found')


window = Tk()
window.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение")
window.geometry('800x640')
lbl = Label(window, text="Мониторинг систем")
tx = Text(window)
tx.grid(column=0, row=2)
tx.insert(INSERT, "")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text='Старт', command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=1)
btn = Button(window, text='Стоп', command=click)
btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944904/10941639

Comment: @Михаил Муругов Спасибо, только это не решает проблемы как остановку связать с кнопкой Финиш

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39556017/10941639 https://stackoverflow.com/a/27051185/10941639